# Adjusting the frequency and the magnitude axis of MATLAB fft

Tags: matlab

I wrote a small script to  get the fft of a sinus signal :

```
    N = 1000; % number of samples 
n = (0:N-1)'; % generate a vector n for x[n]
Fs_normal = 36621.09375;
%generate a signal in pass-band, N samples and simulate filter
f0 = 1000; % set 1000 Hz 
x= sin(2*pi*f0*n/Fs_normal); % input signal
figure(3);
stem(x),title('sinus wave with 1000 Hz (n)'),grid;
figure(4);
plot(abs(fft(x))),grid,title('FFT of sin wave with 1000 Hz  frequency');
```

here is the fft result that I get :

[image]

as you can see the axis doesn't make any sense ( at least to me), is there a way to get this the right way ?

Comment: I suggest reading into the [theory of sampling and DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) (see also: [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)). If your problem is the two peaks, that is. Your question is far from clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFT gives you 1000 bins

```
freqvals = [0:N-1]/N * Fs_normal;
plot(freqvals, abs(fft(x))),grid,title('FFT of sin wave with 1000 Hz  frequency');
```

You have to add the scale on your own. The whole FFT gives you also 1000 complex coefficients back when you give it 1000 samples. The range is from 0 to the sampling frequency.

Bins are separated by a frequency shift of `Fs_normal/N`.